# Node.js, Hapi.js, EJS: reply.view file: ok on mac, "not found" on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, macos, ubuntu, ejs, hapi.js

I'm moving a node.js server from development on my Laptop running Mac to Production on a hosted server running Ubuntu 12.04.

Doing tests to make sure everything works, I get the following error in the Ubuntu Console:

```
Debug: hapi, internal, implementation, error 
Error: View file not found: /var/local/app/pages/templates/appLogin.html
```

If in the console I type `cd /var/local/app/pages/templates/` and then `ls`, `appLogin.html` shows up.

On my mac, everything works fine.

This is how I setup EJS with Hapi.js:

```
var Ejs = require('ejs');
Ejs.registerHelper = function (name, fn) {
    engine.module.filters[name] = fn;
};
var serverOptions= {
cors: true,
files: { relativeTo: __dirname },
views: {
    engines: {
        html: {module: Ejs} },
        path: __dirname + '/pages/templates'
    }
};
var server = Hapi.createServer('localhost', '8000', serverOptions );
```

Why the difference? What am I missing here?

Comment: you should add `allowAbsolutePaths: true` into view options.